# PHP error_log Msg Type 1, Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

Tags: php

An error with the php error_log function when selecting message_type 1 and sending an email. Any value I place in the extra_headers parameter, stops any email being received and the error created.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: error-404@'.substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],4)."\r\n";

$log = var_export(debug_backtrace(), true);

error_log("<HTML><body><h1>404 ERROR: $today</h1><br /><p>$log</p></body></HTML>", 1, "webmaster@domain.com", $headers);
```

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  error_log(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in .....

Current PHP version: 5.6.24

Thanks.

Comment: what os is your webserver running on? In case it's *nix, try removing the `\r`-entities from the headers

Comment: Sorry, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (FastHosts)

Comment: You have an additional closing parenthesis in the middle of your error_log() arguments (after the `$destination`) - is this just a typo in your question? (Otherwise I would expect this to generate some kind of parse error?) Personally, I've had problems manually setting the `MIME-Version` header in the past - I would try removing that (although that doesn't sound like the cause of the problem?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me. Not too sure how correct this solution is.

```
//create a boundary string. It must be unique so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: $from_name <$from_mail> \r\nReply-To: $from_mail";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";

error_log($sMsg, 1, $emailto, $headers);
```

I hope it helps somebody else.

Thank you for all your replies.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [function `error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) for argument `$extra_headers` says:

> This message type uses the same internal function as [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) does.

The documentation of function `mail()` says for `$additional_headers`:

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a `CRLF` (`\r\n`)

This is (I hope) the reason you use `CRLF` (`\r\n`) to separate the lines in the mail header.

However, the same documentation page also says in a note, several paragraphs below:

> If messages are not received, try using a `LF` (`\n`) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably [`» qmail`](http://www.qmail.org)) replace `LF` by `CRLF` automatically (which leads to doubling `CR` if `CRLF` is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with [`» RFC 2822`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822).

I cannot tell about `qmail` but I encountered the same behaviour when the email server was `sendmail`. The problem vanished when I used `LF` (`\n`) as the end-of-line marker in the headers.

Comment: `$headers = "From: someone@something.com\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";`
Not working, no email received. @axiac

Comment: Does PHP still reports an error when it executes the `error_log()` call? If it doesn't, that means it did its job properly and the cause of the email not being received is somewhere else. Check the logs of the email server. Maybe it cannot relay the email or there is another problem on its side.

Comment: `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  error_log(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in...` Yes, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not end extra_header with newline.
Below code is OK:

```
error_log("sometext", 1, "ohmyson@gmail.com",
    "Subject: Foo\nFrom: Rizzlas@my.domain");
```